# jquery toggling a tag but it should behave click and again click only

Tags: jquery

html

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
</ul>
<br clear="all" />
<div>some text</div>
```

css

```
ul{
    list-style: none;
}
li{
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px;
}
div{
    background-color: red;
    height: 200px;
}
```

jquery

```
$('li a').toggle(function(e){
   $('div').toggle(); 
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8gDTM/)

My key question is why a tag is getting toggle function rather it should toggle div only.

**Edit**

$('li a').toggle() function is click and again click function. but $('div').toggle() function is to show and hide. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you going to do like this: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8gDTM/2/)

```
$('li a').toggle(function(e){
   $('div').hide(); 
 e.preventDefault();
}, function(){ 
    $('div').show();
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

change `toggle` to `click`

`a` tag is getting `toggle` as you are using `.toggle()` event with it.

```
$('li a').click(function(e){ //change toggle to click
   $('div').toggle(); 
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

`$('li a').toggle()` function need to be used like this

`$('li a').toggle(function(){},function(){})`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/8gDTM/1/)

```
$('li a').toggle(function (e) {
    $('div').toggle();
    alert('1');
    e.preventDefault();
}, function (e) {
    $('div').toggle();
    alert('2');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```